# How can I make python recognize a word and separate it into a new column?

Tags: python, dataset, classification

I would like to know if there is a way for python to recognize the colors of each record and separate them into a separate column.

That is, we have the following data:

```
ID  CODE        DESCRIPTION                     PRICE
1   85473254        Mountain jacket blue        30,99
2   54123654        Boots pink                  23.45
3   45236574        Buff sky blue               20.50
4   12547835        All set mountain black      90.99
```

And I want to get the following:

```
ID  CODE            DESCRIPTION             COLOR       PRICE
1   85473254        Mountain jacket         Blue        30,99
2   54123654        Boots                   Pink        23.45
3   45236574        Buff                   Sky blue     20.50
4   12547835        All set mountain        Black       90.99
```

Maybe there is any way to train python with a dataset of colors so that it recognizes and separates each color of every registry?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maintain a list of all possible colors, and then form a regex alternation of that.  Then, use `str.extract` to find the color in each description.

```py
colors = ['sky blue', 'pink', 'blue', 'black']
regex = r'\b(' + '|'.join(colors) + r')$'
df["COLOR"] = df["DESCRIPTION"].str.extract(regex, flags=re.I)
```